# Gridmvc filtering without query in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, http-post

I'm using GridMvc and I'm filtering data. I'd like to hide filter query in the url like http://www.mypage.com/Overview?Name=yyy
My form is defined as:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST"  action="@Url.Action("Filter", Request.QueryString)">
    <div class="form-group>
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Name, new { placeholder = "Filter", @class = "form-control" })

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(FilterModel model)
```

But I always see the query. It's possible to hide query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cound hide your query if you put all you data in hidden fields instead of `Request.QueryString`.

I mean if your `Request.QueryString` looks like `param1=test1&param2=test2` you should render you view like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST"  action="@Url.Action("Filter")">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="test1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="test2" />
    <div class="form-group>
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Name, new { placeholder = "Filter", @class = "form-control" })

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

MVC binding will bind all hidden values on **POST** according to `name` property of this `hidden` `input`s.

You should just fill inputs value (replace test1 and test2 with your values from `Request.QueryString`)

Comment: My `Request.QueryString` looks like `Name=JohnDoe`. I'm not sure if it is possible to have `<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="JohnDoe">` and `<input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Filter" type="text" value="JohnDoe">` in one form.

Comment: @user2250152 why not? Try it